# I wrote following code to make grid in the Pycharm. Unable to make mathematical calulations

Tags: python, grid, wxwidgets, calculation

I wrote the following code to make grid in the Pycharm. Unable to make mathematical calculations

```py
import wx
import wx.grid as grid

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size = (600, 800))

        #self.panel = wx.Panel (self)

        self.panel = MyPanel(self)

class MyPanel(wx.Panel) : 
    def __init__(self, parent) :
        super(MyPanel, self). __init__(parent)

        madrid  =   grid.Grid(self)
        madrid.CreateGrid(40, 8)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(madrid, 1 , wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MyApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         self.frame = MyFrame(parent=None, title="Electrical Sizing File")
         self.frame.Show()
         return True

app =   MyApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hello Sudhanva, welcome to stack overflow. You will probably get more/better answers if you add some information about what you expect the code to output, and what it actually is outputting.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, you don't have any calculations in the code you show, so it's really impossible to say what your problem is.

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.